# Tizen studio gear s3 smartwatch saving text file

Tags: c, permissions, native, fopen, tizen

I am using Tizen Studio to create a native smartwatch app for a Samsung Gear S3. I want to record accelerometer data and store it in a csv text file, however I can't seem to access any files. If I use app_get_data_path(), it returns a path to the apps private storage which cannot be accesed through device manager (I want to pull this data to my PC for use in an ML model). So I am trying to use the media folders within the device itself (as recommended by some forum posts), which I have given permissions for in the manifest file.

Below is the code I am using to attempt to open the file:

```
ad->fptr = fopen("/opt/usr/media/documents/test.txt", "w");
fprintf(ad->fptr, "test");
fclose(ad->fptr);
```

When I insert a breakpoint after attempting to create the file, debugging log shows:

```
Temporary breakpoint 2, main (argc=30, argv=0xfffef1d4) at ../src\get_accel_data_log.c:192
192     appdata_s ad = {0,};
[New Thread 11492]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7238098 in ?? ()
[New Thread 11493]
[New Thread 11494]
[New Thread 11495]
[New Thread 11496]
[New Thread 11497]
```

I am finding this IDE really hard to debug with and use in general, if anyone has any experience or ideas I'd be very grateful. I will happily provide any more info as I know I have given the bare minimum. Thanks!

Comment: put  `if (!ad->fptr) perror("XXX");` after fopen line and write back the result.

Comment: @GreenTree ok I'm not sure perror is even showing but I do get a segmentation error. I am doing the file creation on a button click callback if that affects anything?

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7238098 in ?? ()

Comment: Generally, files created by an application is not accessible (open) to sdb. You need to consider uploading files via network connection.